# Anyone know of a good technical arch diagram or white paper article for SharePoint security?

Tags: security

Anyone know of a good technical arch diagram or white paper article focused SharePoint security?

Mod's, I know this isn't a coding question so feel free to delete it if it violates the rules and I apologize if it does.

Comment: This site is for *anything* SharePoint, not just coding questions. I think it just happens that more coders find this site than other SharePoint users, so more coding questions get posted. So the scope of your question (SharePoint Security) is a good candidate for here.

Answer (score 2):

Spencer Harbar posts a lot of information on his blog regarding what he terms Platform Hygiene - suggests practices and techniques to keep your system from breaking. I assume some of this content will include security, so it's definitely worth a read.

http://www.harbar.net/category/5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of information you need. If you want to know something about users, groups and permissions security, try this link

http://navdeep19.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/overview-of-the-sharepoint-2010-security-model/

Or you need something about authentication, Kerberos/NTLM or data security?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with [Security and Authentication for SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff601873.aspx).

SharePoint 2010 Security deserves a whole book in itself so I suggest you have a read through the documentation then come back if you have any specific queries.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 is huge platform. Before learning SharePoint security, you need to know the following:

- SharePoint 2010 works on Windows Server 2008 Active Directory for production environment.
- SharePoint 2010 Web application is hosted by IIS Web Server 7.0 or 7.5
- SharePoint 2010 database is stored by SQL Server 2008

When it comes to SharePoint security, you should consider what you need to secure, such as Web application, Databases, User Information account...then you continue to consider authentications that SharePoint 2010 supports, such as Claim-based authentication or security solutions, which have been running on Active Directory.

I give you further resources:

- [Secure SharePoint 2010 infrastructure fundamentally](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/Secure-SharePoint-2010-infrastructure-fundamentally.aspx)
- [Claim-Based Identity for Windows white paper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9ca5c685-3172-4d8f-81cb-1a59bdc9f7e3&displaylang=en)
- [Security and protection Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010][3]
- [Security planning for sites and content SharePoint Server 2010][4]
- [SharePoint 2010 Security Hardening][5]
- [Server 2008 and IIS7 Hardening for Secure SharePoint Extranet][6]

Because I haven't been SharePoint Developer, thus I can just give you resources concerning infrastructure and basics of SharePoint 2010 security.